# How to return Objects without changing their Type in Powershell?

Tags: function, powershell, object, ms-word, ms-office

I created a function to open a .docx file:

```
Function OpenWordDoc($Filename)

{
    $objWord = New-Object -comobject Word.Application  
    $objWord.Visible = $True;
    $objWord.Documents.Open($Filename)
    $objSelection = $objWord.Selection
    Return $objSelection;
}
```

I'm calling it like this:

```
$doc=OpenWordDoc -Filename "C:\Users\$UserName\Desktop\test.docx";
```

Now I want to call the method `$doc.TypeText("test")` to add some text, but this only works when i run the script without going trough the step of making a function.
I noticed that after I `Return $ObjSelection;` and save it in `$doc`, `$doc` ist not the same ObjectType. Thats why I cant call the method anymore.

How do I set `$doc` to the exact same as `$ObjSelection` without making any of it global?

Comment: `Return $objSelection` -> `,$objSelection`

Comment: @PetSerAl this doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are *not* actually seeing the return type being changed; what you are seeing is one of the most common pitfalls of PowerShell. In fact, you have encountered Pitfall #1 as described in my article [A Plethora of PowerShell Pitfalls](https://www.simple-talk.com/sysadmin/powershell/a-plethora-of-powershell-pitfalls/) on Simple-Talk.com. I encourage you to go over there first--the pitfalls are presented in a quiz format--to allow you to think about what the issues may be before the answer is revealed. I'll wait.

OK, so if you've perused the article, you now know that the flexibility with which PowerShell returns "stuff" from a function is what is tripping you up here. Specifically, the line `$objWord.Documents.Open($Filename)` sends output to stdout, and *everything* sent to stdout is included in what is returned from your function! In order to make your function return *only* `$objSelection` you just need to suppress the output from the line above. There are at least 5 ways to do that. One popular one is just to cast it to void:

```
[void] $objWord.Documents.Open($Filename)
```

Comment: Thanks alot! That was what I was searching for.
Btw great article you wrote there.